# On Client-side Insert/Edit Start Event in Telerik RedGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am using `Telerik in ASP.NET 4.0`. Is there is any client side event which triggers while the edit or insert forms show?

I need to perform some action in that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I am using,

```
              Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoad);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the event handler for all RadGrid commands in your grid by doing the following:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ...
    <ClientSettings>
        <ClientEvents OnCommand="GridCommand" ...
```

Then figure out what command was called in this JavaScript function:

```
function GridCommand (sender, args) {
    if (args.get_commandName() === "Edit") {
        // do something!
    }
}
```